# Windows mode authentication with default Sql provider membership; is it possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

Can I use the windows authentication mode to create the authentication token with Windows login credentials and then confirm authentication with sql membership provider? Or is Windows login in itself an authentication confirmation when you choose windows authentication mode?